# How can I be mega Mario/Luigi on the world map?

Tags: new-super-mario-bros

In New Super Mario Bros., how can I complete a level as "mega" Mario/Luigi, and stay "mega"?  I think I've seen a video of someone doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no.  I think what you saw was a fan video.

Sorry to burst your bubble :(

Comment: What is a "fan video"?

Comment: It's a video of something made by a fan of that thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that if you eat the mega mushroom almost exactly before you jump on the flag at the end of the level. That way, you are still big while it ends. There isn't actually an extra reward or prize for doing that, so it is pretty much a worthless thing to do. I only know this from playing myself, so unfortunately I can't recommend any websites to visit.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible within the constraints of the game, but by using a memory modifier (such an Action Replay card) you can force the Mega Mario powerup value to "on" and Mario will be large on the World Map. I'm not sure if this is a glitch or some sort of unused feature, but it is probably the former.

The same code should allow you to be giant in the levels for an unlimited amount of time.